# Jumps in the plot made in R

Tags: r, plot, graph

I am quite experienced user so I am quite iritating  by the fact that I cannot find the answer by myself... I need to plot a function, which has jump in it's definition but everywhere else it is continuous and I want to see the jump on the graph. But R want to make it continous on the whole range and that makes funny line which connect these two areas, but I need them to be visualy separated; I know that maybe dots instead of lines would make the work but I want to show that the function is continous everywhere else except the jump... in the definition of function I use indicator functions so the code is something like

```
for_plotting <- function(x){  (1/2 + x/2)*(x>=0.5) + (10*x^3)*(x<0.5)} 
plot(for_plotting,0,1)
```

(I also tried it with >= and <= together and it does not help)
Is there a way how to do it? I need to do the picture into my thesis so you advice is very welcome :)

[image]

Comment: Hi Jozef. Any chance you could accept one of these answers?

Comment: I am terribly sorry, I totally forgot that I've asked this question once. The thesis is already finished and defended. Thank you guys for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `ggplot2` like Jan Sila suggested, but you can use base plot to do this as well:

```
for_plotting <- function(x){  (1/2 + x/2)*(x>=0.5) + (10*x^3)*(x<0.5)} 
t1 <- 0:49/100
x1 <- for_plotting(t1)
t2 <- 50:100/100
x2 <- for_plotting(t2)

plot(t1,x1,xlim=c(0,1),type="l",col="red")
lines(t2,x2,col="blue")
```

yielding:

[image]

Comment: Well, mark it correct then please. And an upvote (when you get to 15 points) would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use simple plot I would suggest create empty plot canvas of sizes you want, say x from 0 to 10, then add the two segments with command *lines*...

Or

Similarly can use ggplot - create ggplot()+geom_line(segment1)+geom_line(segment 2 specs) 
Have a look at ggplot2 docs. I will try to produce some code once I'm with my laptop.

Comment: How to plot empty canvas?
Second thing, this was unfortunate example, in reality I have more complicated functions, not just lines, should I use command _curve_?